# Can I view my Microsoft Exchange Online Archive via Davmail in Thunderbird

Tags: email, smtp, thunderbird, exchange

I have successfully set up Davmail on Ubuntu 14 and am able to read, receive and send mail on my Exchange account in Thunderbird. This page was a big help!:

http://nknu.net/ubuntu-14-04-exchange-configuration-thunderbird-pidgin/

I set the account up as IMAP, so I can also browse folders. One thing I can't seem to do is subscribe to or otherwise access the "Online Archive" - a copy of my Inbox and subfolders for all mail more than a year old (my IT department's policy). Davmail release notes say that this is possible but I can't find any guides on how to view this archive folder in Thunderbird, or any other mail clients. Can anyone suggest what to do or what to read?

Cheers, 
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posters in this thread claim success although the explanation of what options need to be changed lacks detail.

http://sourceforge.net/p/davmail/support-requests/134/

I have the URLs but I need more specific instructions in how to change the settings of Davmail and my email clients. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The link posted by Ryan led me to this working solution:

You need to set up a second e-mail account in your mail client with the base path (aka IMAP server directory) set to "/archive/"

In Thunderbird, this can be achieved in these steps:

- Create another E-Mail acount in Thunderbird, exactly as your original one
- Before  doing anything else (don't browse your new mailbox yet) edit the new account's settings:

  - Rename the account name to something else than your original profile (e.g. "Archive")
  - Go to `Server Settings`, click `Advanced`, and set `IMAP server directory` to "/archive/".
- Now you can browse the folders. Ignore the INBOX though, it contains the non-archived inbox.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a workaround to avoid having two different accounts on Thunderbird, by defining a personal policy on top of the IT department's default ones. Namely, you go to Outlook (Web) Settings, All Settings, Retention policies, add two new (personal) policies that never archive or delete messages. Then right click on Inbox and Sent folders, Assign Policy, Personal (Never ...).

Finally I moved by hand all the e-mails from the In-Place Archive, to the normal "Archive" from the normal Inbox, or any other folder you would like in your normal account. The same with the "Sent" folder from the In-Place Archive.